# openerp error AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Tags: python, odoo

I was trying to use multi parameter in my code then this error came up I have tried everything still I am not able to rectify this error .Pls tell me how can I correct this,. my code is as follows

```py
class client_client(osv.osv):
    def totalsum(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, args, context=None):
        tsum = {}
        for dx in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            tsum[dx.id] = (dx.cp1val + dx.cp2val)
            print tsum
        return tsum

    def totalsum_val(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        tqw = {}

        for cl in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=None):
            tqw[cl.id] = (cl.cp1val + cl.cp2val + 2)
        return tqw.keys()


    _name = 'client.client'

    _columns = {
        'total': fields.function(totalsum, type='integer', string='Total', help="Total sum",
                                 store={'client.client': (totalsum_val, ['cp1val', 'cp2val'], 10)}, multi='calc'),
        'total2': fields.function(totalsum, type='integer', string='2nd total',
                                  store={'client.client': (totalsum_val, ['cp1val', 'cp2val'], 10)}, multi='calc'),
        'total3': fields.function(totalsum, type='integer', string='3rd total',
                                  store={'client.client': (totalsum_val, ['cp1val', 'cp2val'], 10)}, multi='calc'),
        'cp1val': fields.integer('NO 1', size=45, help="First no to be added", required=True),
        'cp2val': fields.integer('NO 2', size=45, help="Second no to be added", required=True),
    }

    _defaults = {
    }
```

Basically What I want to do right now is to add two no's cp1val,cp2val in totalsum() function ,then using multi and store parameter I want to add the same cp1val,cp2val with integer 2 in totalsum_val function ,but I'm not getting it only the totalsum function is executing correctly and I'm getting its output in total field. Please help me on this

Here is log

```
Server Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/subash/Openerp_11_12_13/web/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
File "/home/subash/Openerp_11_12_13/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
File "/home/subash/Openerp_11_12_13/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
res = fn(db, uid, *params)
File "/home/subash/Openerp_11_12_13/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 188, in execute_kw
return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
File "/home/subash/Openerp_11_12_13/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 131, in wrapper
return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/subash/Openerp_11_12_13/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 197, in execute
res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
File "/home/subash/Openerp_11_12_13/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 185, in execute_cr
return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
File "/home/subash/Openerp_11_12_13/server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 4500, in create
self.pool.get(object)._store_set_values(cr, user, ids, fields2, context)
File "/home/subash/Openerp_11_12_13/server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 4627, in _store_set_values
result = self._columns[val[0]].get(cr, self, ids, val, SUPERUSER_ID, context=context)
File "/home/subash/Openerp_11_12_13/server/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 1144, in get
for field, value in result[id].iteritems():
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Comment: just simply return `tqw`, may be issue of `keys().`

Comment: I have tried it too ,It was of no use

Comment: in which function do you have problem ? can you paste sever log?

Comment: actually totalsum function is working correctly ,the problem is with totalsum_val function where I'm using multi and store parameter ..

Answer (score 2):

for multi you have to change your result dictionary of that function into following form:

```
{'id1':{
        'field1':value,
        'field2':value,
        'field3':value,
       },
 'id2':{and so on...
}
```

so for your example your function have to look like:

```
def totalsum(self,cr,uid,ids,field_name,args,context=None):
     tsum={}
     for dx in self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context):
          tsum[dx.id]={
                       'total':#value here,
                       'total2':#value here,
                       'total3':#value here,
                      }
          print tsum
     return tsum
```

Comment: Does that mean whenever we use multi , we have to seperately assign values to it .? Why is that?

Comment: if you use multi, you have to do it that way. oh, i didn't see, that you're using your second function as multi, too. just change it the way the first function (totalsum()) was changed.